# Highcharts format legend names

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is my codepen : [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKQwxm)

I have a pie chart showing the status of vehicles. Legend shows 'slice' instead of the names of status. How to format this?

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: "pointer",
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  }
```

Also, when the same used in my project, graph is plotted with default colors and not the ones mentioned in the array. However it works fine in codepen or fiddle.

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      colors: [
        "#50B432",


 "#ED561B",
    "#DDDF00",
    "#24CBE5",
    "#64E572",
    "#FF9655",
    "#FFF263",
    "#6AF9C4"
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`legend.labelFormat`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/legend.labelFormat), for example: `labelFormat: '{status}'` demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKQxqo

Alternatively change `status` to `name` in your data options (default format for pie slice is `{name}`): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKQxEo

Second issue: it's hard to guess without live demo. You can work around the issue by setting [`plotOptions.pie.color`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.colors). Just a guess, but maybe you have in your code `Highcharts.setOptions()` multiple times?